# Golang context.WithTimeout doesn't work with exec.CommandContext "su -c" command

Tags: go, unix, su

This code works properly, it prints `Timeout`:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1000 * time.Millisecond)
process := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "5")

processOutBytes, err := process.Output()

if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
    fmt.Println("Timeout")
}
```

But this, with **just another command**, is not. Process can work infinitely!

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1000 * time.Millisecond)
process := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "su", "-", "myuser", "-c", "python3 main.py")

processOutBytes, err := process.Output()

if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
    fmt.Println("Timeout")
}
```

Running on Ubuntu 20.04 inside docker container based on ubuntu:20.04. Why is this so and how to make the second code work?

Comment: Are you sure there's not an error other than context.DeadlineExceeded returned?

Comment: Are you even sure the process didn't complete before the context timed out?

Comment: The timeout only applies to the `su` process, the next process called will continue to run.

Comment: Peter, Elias Van Ootegem, yes, sure. For example, if I have “while True: pass” in main.py, the process.Output() will work infinitely.

Comment: @sadfun were you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 8):

The timeout only applies to the process started by `exec`, it won't kill any child processes. In your case it will kill the `su` but not the next `python3` process.

To kill all children started by a given process you can start it in a new process group and kill the entire group by sending `SIGKILL` to `-pid` (negative pid), like so:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1000 * time.Millisecond)
process := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "su", "-", "myuser", "-c", "python3 main.py")

process.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
go func() {
    <-ctx.Done()
    if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
        syscall.Kill(-process.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
    }
}()

processOutBytes, err := process.Output()
cancel()

if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
    fmt.Println("Timeout")
}
```

Note also that the code relying on `syscall` isn't portable; it won't even compile on Windows, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is not to kill child python process. The main problem is that with this command ctx is **never done**. Try to put, for example, "while True: pass" in main.py - process.Output() function will never return anything. Even ctx.Done() channel will never trigger your process kill goroutine.

Comment: Have you tried my code? ctx will be done after the deadline.

Comment: Of course I tried - in my case, ctx will NOT be done after the deadline. Even if we use `<-time.After(1000 * time.Millisecond)` as trigger for your killer goroutine, it doesn't kill `process`, `process.Output()` still can work infinitely.

However, I found a simple solution: replace `process.Output()` with `process.Run()` and handle stdout manually, with process.StdoutPipe(). In this case, context can done and kill `process`. 

But your answer is useful too - in my project I also need to kill child processes of `process`.

Comment: @rus If process exits before running the command "syscall.Kill(-process.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)", would not it say process not found and cannot kill the child process?