# Go context.WithTimeout does not work with exec.CommandContext sudo commands, even if I try to kill child processes. What is going on? Am on Linux

Tags: linux, go, process, child-process, pid

I have been using exec.CommandContext to run sudo commands in my Go packages, and it works. Nowadays, I am trying to add a timeout so that the command just terminates if it does not finish after the timeout ends. However, I realized the RunAsSudo function would never return. I read [Golang context.WithTimeout doesn't work with exec.CommandContext "su -c" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750520/golang-context-withtimeout-doesnt-work-with-exec-commandcontext-su-c-command) and thus modified RunAsSudo accordingly, but the function still does not return.
Below is the original RunAsSudo, Version 1:

```
myCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 8*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err := e.RunAsSudo(myCtx, f.commandContext, cmd)

func RunAsSudo(ctx context.Context, exc exec.CommandContext, command string) (err error) {
    cmd := exc(ctx, "/bin/bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("sudo %s", command))

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()

    return
}
```

modified RunAsSudo version 2, which still does not work:

```
func RunAsSudoWithTimeout(ctx context.Context, exc exec.CommandContext, command string) (error) {
    cmd := exc(rpiCtx, "/bin/bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("sudo %s", command))
    
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
            syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
        }
    }()

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    return err
}
```

However, I noticed that if I replaced `cmd` with something that does not require sudo permission eg `cmd := exc(ctx, "/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 1h")`, RunAsSudo (both versions 1 and 2) returns after the timeout.
Version 3 of RunAsSudo, which returns after the timeout:

```
func RunAsSudo(ctx context.Context, exc exec.CommandContext, command string) (err error) {
    errs := make(chan error, 1)
    cmd := exc(ctx, "/bin/bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("sudo %s", command))

    if stdout != nil {
        cmd.Stdout = stdout
    }

    if stderr != nil {
        cmd.Stderr = stderr
    }
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
    go func() {
        defer close(errs)
        err := cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
            errs <- err
            return
        }
        err = cmd.Wait()
        errs <- err
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
            syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
            fmt.Println("syskill!")
        }
        return ctx.Err()
    case err := <-errs:
        return err
    }
}
```

How come version 3 returns after the timeout but not version 2 or 1? Is version 3 the right approach to terminating processes started by exec.CommandContext after a timeout? Thanks a lot~~

Comment: For the same reason in the linked answer, you’re not killing the child process.

Comment: This `-cmd.Process.Pid`? Drop the minus.

Comment: @colm.anseo, the `-` is how you signify a posix process group, but you still can’t kill the process if you don’t have permission to do so.

Comment: @JimB How do I kill the child processes then?

Comment: Fist check the error from the syscall, I assume it’s a permission problem. If you need to elevate permissions with sudo to start the process, then you probably need to use sudo to kill the same process.

Comment: @JimB yes you are right, it was a permission problem. I needed sudo to kill the process.